# jquery and jsp - still saving in cache even cache:false and response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, caching

I have a problem. I still can see that my cache is still increasing after I have placed this codes on my jsp.

```
<% response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); %>
```

and in my javascript/jquery which resides on the same jsp:

```
function waitForMsg() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url : contextPath + "/groupChat",
        async: true,
        cache: false,

        success: function (data) {
            $("#divChatMessageTable").load(contextPath + "/groupChat/message");
            setTimeout(waitForMsg, 1000);   
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            setTimeout(waitForMsg, 15000);  
        }
    });
    if ($("#divChatMessageTable").height() > tableHeight) {
        scrollToBottomChat ();
        tableHeight = $("#divChatMessageTable").height();
    }
}
```

I have set the `cache:false` in the jquery.

Btw, Im using Firefox.

Please help.

Comment: what is the purpose of the first ajax call.. it sends no data and does nothing with any response? Also should move the `setTimeout` to success callback of `load` to allow for some time for that call to be made. Simlilarly, you are trying to test height of new content before it is loaded and it should be done within success callback of `load` also

Comment: @charlietfl SO far its working. Its a simple chat. What it does is calling query every second. Im really new to this thing. Could you please paste some codes you suggested. I tried your suggestion but it seems that I don't know how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: OK.. well can you explain why or if call to `contextPath + "/groupChat"` is necessary... it sends nothing and does nothing with response.. can probably remove it and simply do the `load` with callback to check table height

Comment: @charlietfl `contextPath + "/groupChat"` is used to load the data to the html/jsp table that displays chat. I'll try removing it. Thanks.

Comment: but it isn't doing what you say. The response is `data` in `success: function (data)` but it never gets used. Instead another ajax call using `load` is being made to the other url

Answer (score 1):

You can likely get rid of the initial ajax call and just keep the `load` call ( which is also ajax). The one difference below is adding a success callback to `load` method so you aren't testing height of the new content before it has been inserted

```
function waitForMsg() {

    $("#divChatMessageTable").load(contextPath + "/groupChat/message", function({ 
        /* new content now exists*/
        if($("#divChatMessageTable").height() > tableHeight) {
            scrollToBottomChat();
            tableHeight = $("#divChatMessageTable").height();
        }
        setTimeout(waitForMsg, 1000);    
    });


}
```

API refrence for `load` http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: i think you had more of a timing overlap than a cache problem. I've never had cache issues before with jQuery ajax

Comment: I know this might be irrelevant but I wanna know if there is an ajax function that will load data only when a client posted data to the server. I mean I want to get rid of the timer because it continually calls a query which I think is not good for the server. Im not sure.

Comment: no.. you can't push from server with ajax, need to use a websocket for that

Comment: yes..is different protocol than http. The other thing you can do is not send new data unless there is new data to send

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by adding `no-store, must-revalidate`.

The code:

```
<% response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); %>
```